# Convert Large CSV into multiple JSON arrays of fixed records (eg. 100 records json arrays ) using Shell

Tags: json, bash, shell, csvtojson

How do i convert a large CSV into JSON Arrays of fixed record set ( JSON arrays of 100 records ) through SHELL script or command line?

Eg. of Input CSV file:

```
identifier,type,locale
91617676848,MSISDN,es_ES
91652560975,MSISDN,es_ES
91636563675,MSISDN,es_ES
```

Expected output:

```
1.json  (json array having 100 array records)
  [
  {
    "identifier": "91617676848",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  {
    "identifier": "91652560975",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  }
  ]


  2.json (json array having 100 array records)
  [
  {
    "identifier": "91636563675",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .

  {
    "identifier": "91636563999",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple php script (i called it `converter.php`).

You can call as is: `php converter.php test.csv` where test.csv contains and default csv data with the first line as header.

```
<?php
    // open the file passed as parameter
    // Ex: php converter.php test.csv
    // Where test.csv contains the data passed on question
    if (($handle = fopen($argv[1], 'r')) !== false) {
            $count = 0;
            $lines = [];
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '\'')) !== false) {
                    if ($count == 0) {
                        $headers = $data;
                    } else {
                        $lines[] = array_combine($headers, $data);
                    }
                    $count++;
            }
            // Here, separate in array of arrays with 100 elements on each
            // On test i used 2 on second parameter of array_chunk to test with your toy data
            $groups = array_chunk($lines, 100);
            foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
                    file_put_contents('json_data-'.$key.'.json', json_encode($group));
            }
    }
```

I run locally and i separated the files by two elements to test it and resulted in two files saved locally, named `json_data-<key>.json`

And the results are here:

- json_data-0.json:

  [
  {"identifier":"91617676848","type":"MSISDN","locale":"es_ES"},{"identifier":"91652560975","type":"MSISDN","locale":"es_ES"}
  ]
- json_data-1.json:

  [
  {"identifier":"91636563675","type":"MSISDN","locale":"es_ES"}
  ]

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try an `awk` solution:

```
awk -v bs=10 '
    NR == 1 {
        cols = split($0, header, ",")
        next
    }
    {
        if ((NR - 1) % bs == 1) {
            file = sprintf("%d.json", ++n)
            print "[\n  {" > file
        } else {
            print ",\n  {" >> file
        }
        split($0, a, ",")
        for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
            printf("    \"%s\": \"%s\"", header[i], a[i]) >> file
            print (i < cols) ? "," : "" >> file
        }
        printf "%s", "  }" >> file
    }
    (NR - 1) % bs == 0 {
        print "\n]" >> file
        close(file)
    }
    END {
        if ((NR - 1) % bs != 0) print "\n]" >> file
    }
' input.csv
```

The variable `bs` holds a number of arrays per file.
It processes the input file line by line and has so many conditional branches to produce proper json files. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` implementation, task can be completed by repeatedly slicing the line range from the file (2-101, 102-201, ...) until the end of the file. Code below uses `sed` to extract line, and `csvjson` to format each block into JSON.

You can replace any of your favorite tools (there are few csv to json alternatives).

Code slightly more verbose that needed.

```
#! /bin/sh
csv=$1
lines=$(wc -l < $csv)
blocks=$((1+(lines-1)/100))
for (( i=1 ; i <= blocks ; i++ )) ; do
    sed -ne "1p;$((i*100-98)),$((i*100+1))p" $csv | csvjson -i2 > $i.json
done
```

Assuming reasonable file size, reprocessing the input file will not incur lot of overhead